# handling csv files fgetcsv & str_getcsv?

Tags: php

Is **fgetcsv** better than **str_getcsv**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is `fgetcsv()` better than `str_getcsv()`?

Yes, when opening from a file. Use `str_getcsv()` only when you have the CSV already as a string in your program.

> Is there a way to only allow `.csv` file types to be displayed in the file upload dialog?

No, unless you use a [Flash wrapper](http://www.swfupload.org/). However, you can detect the file extension with JavaScript, and you *must* accept only `.csv` with PHP (use `pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`).

However, ensuring it has `.csv` does not confirm it is actually a CSV file.

> Should I/do I need to use `ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);`

No, unless it is not working. [The docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings) state there is a small performance penalty in using it. So only use it when it is required. It is also *off* by default. Best to leave less common things in `php.ini` to their default, I have found.

Though make sure `magic_quotes` and `register_globals` are *always off* :)