# Load a CSV file into a Database table?

Tags: mysql, csv, upload, file-get-contents

I am trying to upload CSV data from a website, to a database. I can't used the LOAD_DATA_INFILE as I don't have the user permissions to do this.

I do have access to the file, and so I've used the file_get_contents to put it all into a string, that I then hope to upload to the database.

$a = file_get_contents('file_path');

I'm a bit stuck as to how go about doing it from this point - and I was hoping someone could offer me either a better solution, or some insight into the syntax I need for this!

All help appreciated thanks!

Comment: What scripting language are you using? php? At any rate, a quick web search will find helpful advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using php and I found my answer on another question on the site: [handling csv files fgetcsv & str_getcsv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274109/handling-csv-files-fgetcsv-str-getcsv)

The easiest solution is fgetcsv: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

I hope that helps someone else as I was getting lost looking around the many answers on Google! :)